# Integration of C++ in C infrastructure

Tags: c++, c

C++ is real handy in most projects, but sometimes you just have to integrate with existing C style functions.

How do you do that in a neat way, especially, if you work with strings?

I had an idea that I could use construct like this:

```
std::string buffer;
buffer.resize(1024);

GetBackCStyleString(&buffer[0], 1024);
```

But this causes problems with string length, as it returns the resized length. Is there a better way to integrate C functions in C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good solution.  If you want the size to be accurate, call `resize` again after the function returns and you can calculate the actual length.

e.g.

```
buffer.resize(GetBackCStyleString(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
```

if the function returns the length, or

```
GetBackCStyleString(&buffer[0], buffer.size()
buffer.resize(strlen(&buffer[0]));
```

otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer.c_str()` if function takes `const char*` or `const_cast<char*>(buffer.c_str())` if function takes `char*`. In the latter case be cautious

Comment: @BenVoigt: And is guaranteed indirectly in C++03 anyway, by virtue of a few standard bugs. :)

Comment: Also, `&buffer[0]` preserves const-correctness and `const_cast<char*>(buffer.c_str())` does not.

Comment: @Tomalek , can you explain your comment? How does C++03 indirectly guarantee a writable string buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Create a plain `char somebuf[somesize];` buffer and let the C function write into that.
Then create a `std::string` from it using `std::string buffer(somebuf)`.

If the function just wants a `const char *` (i.e. an "input" parameter), simply pass `yourStdString.c_str()` to it.